# Finding the closest geographical point within each group

Tags: r, distance, spatial

I am trying to find the closest point (in my case closest bank) for each bank within each "Year" group. I have tried using st_distance, without success.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
   Year                   geometry                                 bank   Location
7  1838   POINT (759859.6 -728345)                       Bank of Mobile     Mobile
43 1838 POINT (779861.1 -445454.7)         Bank of the State of Alabama Tuscaloosa
58 1838 POINT (819114.6 -285180.1) Bank of the State of Alabama, branch    Decatur
59 1841 POINT (819114.6 -285180.1) Bank of the State of Alabama, branch    Decatur
60 1842 POINT (819114.6 -285180.1) Bank of the State of Alabama, branch    Decatur
67 1838 POINT (853709.4 -267830.7) Bank of the State of Alabama, branch Huntsville
68 1841 POINT (853709.4 -267830.7) Bank of the State of Alabama, branch Huntsville
69 1842 POINT (853709.4 -267830.7) Bank of the State of Alabama, branch Huntsville
79 1838   POINT (759859.6 -728345) Bank of the State of Alabama, branch     Mobile
91 1838 POINT (905601.7 -526517.9) Bank of the State of Alabama, branch Montgomery
```

What I wish to do is to know, for instance, what is the closest bank to, let's say, the "Bank of the State of Alabama, branch" in  "Decatur" in 1838, 1841 and 1842 separately.

For some banks, the minimum distance to another bank should be zero as there were several banks in the same town/city (for instance for "Bank of Mobile" in 1838).

---

Here is a reproducible example:

```
  S1 <- structure(list(Year = c("1838", "1838", "1838", "1841", "1842", 
    "1838", "1841", "1842", "1838", "1838", "1841", "1842", "1838"
    ), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(759859.587499541, -728344.968108917
    ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(779861.05153977, 
    -445454.703808866), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(819114.617375314, 
    -285180.101652618), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(819114.617375314, 
    -285180.101652618), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(819114.617375314, 
    -285180.101652618), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(853709.422752713, 
    -267830.684434561), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(853709.422752713, 
    -267830.684434561), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(853709.422752713, 
    -267830.684434561), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(759859.587499541, 
    -728344.968108917), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(905601.700907393, 
    -526517.946820037), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(759859.587499541, 
    -728344.968108917), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(759859.587499541, 
    -728344.968108917), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(336877.092499058, 
    -301769.66275037), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 336877.092499058, 
    ymin = -728344.968108917, xmax = 905601.700907393, ymax = -267830.684434561
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = NA_integer_, proj4string = "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
    bank = c("Bank of Mobile", "Bank of the State of Alabama", 
    "Bank of the State of Alabama, branch", "Bank of the State of Alabama, branch", 
    "Bank of the State of Alabama, branch", "Bank of the State of Alabama, branch", 
    "Bank of the State of Alabama, branch", "Bank of the State of Alabama, branch", 
    "Bank of the State of Alabama, branch", "Bank of the State of Alabama, branch", "Planters & Merchants Bank", "Planters & Merchants Bank",
    "Bank of the State of Arkansas"), Location = c("Mobile", 
    "Tuscaloosa", "Decatur", "Decatur", "Decatur", "Huntsville", 
    "Huntsville", "Huntsville", "Mobile", "Montgomery", "Mobile", 
    "Mobile", "Little Rock")), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(Year = NA_integer_, 
    bank = NA_integer_, Location = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
    "aggregate", "identity")), row.names = c(7L, 43L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
    67L, 68L, 69L, 79L, 91L, 116L, 117L, 130L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"
    ))
```

Comment: What coordinate system are you using?

Comment: I used "Albers Equal Area Conic Projection" although I think I need to change that because what I need are distances, not areas, to be preserved. (CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future references, here is how I solved the problem. It gives the distance to the 10 closest points (banks):

```
 for (i in 1830:1860) {
   d <- S1c[which(S1c$Date==i),]
   d1 <- st_nn(d, d, returnDist=T, k=11, maxdist=200000)                 #maximum distance 200km
        for(k in 1:11) {
          d[[paste0("neigbor_id_", k)]] = sapply(d1[[1]], "[", k)
          d[[paste0("neighbor_", k)]] =  sapply(d1[[2]], "[", k)
        }                                                                     #Merge output from st_nn with original data
        assign(paste("d_", i, sep = ""), d)                                   #Generates files for each years
        }
    
    #Row bind
d <- rbind(d_1830, d_1831, d_1832, d_1833, d_1834, d_1835, d_1836, d_1837, d_1838, d_1839, d_1840, d_1841, d_1842, d_1843, d_1844, d_1845, d_1846, d_1847, d_1848, d_1849, d_1850, d_1851, d_1852, d_1853, d_1854, d_1855, d_1856, d_1857, d_1858, d_1859, d_1860)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that has arguments allowing you to choose a bank by year, bank name, and location.  It will return an `sf` object with that location and the nearest location from the data.frame that is from the same or later year with a different name & location.

You may need to change the logic for index2, depending on what you're looking for.

```
dist_by_year <- function(x = S1, year = 1841, 
                         bank = 'Bank of the State of Alabama, branch',
                         loc = 'Decatur'){
  x$Year <- as.numeric(x$Year)
  index1 <- which(x$bank == bank & x$Year == year & x$Location == loc)
  
  index2 <- which((x$bank != bank & x$Location != loc)& x$Year >= year )
  
  
  index3 <- st_nearest_feature(x[index1,], x[index2,])
  
  closest <- x[index2,][index3,]
  closest$id <- 'closest'
  target <- x[index1,]
  target$id <- 'target'
  rbind(closest, target)

}
```

Returns:

```
> dist_by_year()
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 759859.6 ymin: -728345 xmax: 819114.6 ymax: -285180.1
CRS:            +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
    Year                                 bank Location      id                   geometry
116 1841            Planters & Merchants Bank   Mobile closest   POINT (759859.6 -728345)
59  1841 Bank of the State of Alabama, branch  Decatur  target POINT (819114.6 -285180.1)
```

Can be piped to `st_distance` for the actual distance:

```
> dist_by_year() %>% st_distance()
Units: [m]
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,]      0.0 447108.8
[2,] 447108.8      0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense. How would I use your solution to calculate the minimum distance for each observation? I am sure there must be a way to automatize it, but I am still quite new at R. Since I have more than 29,000 observations, doing it one by one is out of question.

Comment: purrr::map would probably help.